# Object orientation: error with method in Python

Tags: python

I've made a Python programm with a interface that receives the name of the file and a numerical data. When I create methods to manipulate filename, directory, among others, it returns an error.

I believe the error comes with object orientation. How can I solve this?

I've divided the program in two parts: one to solve my problem (no object orientation) and another to receive user data.

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "teste.py", line 60, in verificaSenha
    if (Procura_nome(nome_arq) == 1):
NameError: global name 'Procura_nome' is not defined
```

The complete code: https://pastebin.com/Br6JAcuR

Problematic method:

```
def Procura_nome(nome_arq):
    dir = Percorre_dir_entrada()
    arquivo = dir + dir[2] + nome_arq + + ".shp"
    os.path.isfile(nome_arq)
    try:
        with open(arquivo, 'r') as f:
            return 1
    except IOError:
        return 0
```

Comment: is `Procura_nome` supposed to be part of the class?

Comment: yes, all methods should be part of the class @depperm

Comment: then you need `self` to be the first parameter in all of the methods like `Procura_nome(self, nome_arq):`

Comment: @depperm How do I reference the method? self.Procura_nome(nome_arq)?

Comment: yes you need to do that too

Comment: I tried, but the error continues :( https://pastebin.com/3g84MKcH

Comment: the exact same error?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "teste2.py", line 60, in verificaSenha
    if (principal(nome_arq, tam_pixel)== 1):
  File "teste2.py", line 129, in principal
    if (Procura_nome(nome_arq) == 1):
  File "teste2.py", line 120, in Procura_nome
    arquivo = dir + dir[2] + nome_arq + + ".shp"
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Comment: so this is a different error I believe because there is an extra `+` in `arquivo = dir + dir[2] + nome_arq + + ".shp"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All python method class must have self param as first argument, this argument refers to the instance of your class, also when using class methods and attributs inside your class you should refer to them with self.

You probably need to add self to all your method class in your file.

You also need to remove one '+' on the 3rd line.

```
def Procura_nome(self, nome_arq):
    dir = self.Percorre_dir_entrada()
    arquivo = dir + dir[2] + nome_arq + ".shp"
    os.path.isfile(nome_arq)
    try:
        with open(arquivo, 'r') as f:
            return 1
    except IOError:
        return 0
```

Your Percorre_dir_entrada and Percorre_dir_saida function are doing exactly the same thing on different files, you should think about doing a generic version who take the file name as param like so :

```
def Percorre_dir(self, file_name):
    achou = 0
    dirlist = os.listdir(".")
    for i in dirlist:
        filename = os.path.abspath(i)
        if((filename.find(file_name)) != -1):
            achou = 1
            return filename
    if(achou == 0):
        return 0
```

then call it :

```
Percorre_dir("Saida")
Percorre_dir("Entrada")
```